# Is it possible to align the title of a ggplot to the right?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am generating a figure that will be used as a column of labels to the right of a three-panel figure, and I would like the title of the figure to right-align as do the labels in the figure itself.

here is a minimal example in which I would like to right-align the title 'words'.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_text(aes(y = 1, x = seq(4), 
                label = c('fee', 'fi', 'fo', 'fum'), 
                hjust = 1)) +      
  opts(title = 'words') + 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,0), limits = c(0,1))
```

Which produces this:

[image]

**update**

The answer by @joran is helpful, but it does not align the words with the labels. changing his code from `hjust=1` to `hjust = 0.96` gets close, but this is more of a hack than a satisfying answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do that with the following:

```
opts(plot.title = theme_text(hjust=1))
```

More generally, [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/+opts%28%29-List) is a reasonably complete list of things that can be altered via `opts` and you can see some example code running through some of these options at Hadley's site [here](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/book/), particularly the section on 'polishing'. Even better would be to buy his book.

**Note**: Since version 0.9.2 `opts` has been replaced by `theme`:

```
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 1))
```

Comment: @joran thanks for the answer and for pointing out these resources; after finding the `opts(title = ...` code, I didn't expect that `, plot.title = ... )` would be a separate argument.

Comment: @joran after playing around with this, I find that the title is not aligned with the label text using `hjust = 1` (see update to O.P.). Is there a way to align the labels and the title?

Comment: @David - No prob. Exploring all the nooks and crannies of `opts` can be a bit of a challenge. Hadley's book sits next to my computer and I'm constantly flipping through it to look something up cause it takes me at least 10-20 times before I start to remember.

Comment: @David - `theme_text(hjust = 0.95)` gets it pretty close to lined up. You can tinker from there.

Comment: @joran thanks. Wasn't sure if I needed to tinker or if there was a better way, at least hjust is a continuous variable.

Comment: In the development version, `hjust = 1` lines it up exactly right.